# Как найти самое частое слово в тексте?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Напишите программу, которая считывает текст из файла (в файле может быть больше одной строки) и выводит самое частое слово в этом тексте и через пробел то, сколько раз оно встретилось. Если таких слов несколько, вывести лексикографически первое (можно использовать оператор < для строк).

В качестве ответа укажите вывод программы, а не саму программу.

Слова, написанные в разных регистрах, считаются одинаковыми.

```py
f=open('D:\dataset_3363_3 (7).txt','r') # cчитываю файл
line=f.readline().lower()
while line:
    line=line.split()    
    s={}
    i1=0
    i2=''
    q=0
    t=[]
    min1=0
    for i in line: # ввожу слова в словарь
        if i not in s: # проверяю есть ли слово в словаре,если есть,то добавляю1 
            s[i]=1
        else:
            s[i]+=1
    for values in s.values(): # нахожу максимальное повторение
        if values>i1:
            i1=values
    for keys , values in s.items():
        if values==i1:
            min1=keys
    for keys , values in s.items(): # если слова встречаются одинаковое кол-во,
        if values==i1:              # то находим  лексикографически первое 
            if min1>keys:
                min1=keys
    print(min1,i1)
    line=f.readline().lower()
f.close()
```

Вроде всё правильно:сам вводил строки-всё правильно,но если прохожу через проверку на степике,то мне вместо правильного ответа шиш
помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Ну так вы забыли про регистр и сделали lower

Comment: пардон.оказывается на регистр системе плевать.

Comment: Так про регистр забыть или не забыть? Текст вопроса противоречит тексту комментария, и ничего не понятно. В том числе непонятно, нужен ли lower в коде или не нужен

Comment: еще раз извините,что запутал вас. Слова в разных регистрах считаются одинаковыми,поэтому в lower приводить надо

Answer (score 3):

Сейчас ищется самое частое слово в каждой строке, а не во всем тексте. Вынеси `s={}` перед циклом, а проверку на частоту делай только после того, как считал все строчки, т.е. после цикла, а не внутри его.

Comment: @ляяя
точно
вот что такое внимательность.спасибо огромное